# messages API twitter Challenge-Response Checks

Tags: django, python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I've seen that twitter changed their endpoints to get and send direct messages, I noticed from a reply from here that it is a workaround to be able to send messages with well-known libraries such as tweepy, but all I need in this case is to list the messages in my inbox.

I've noticed that there is an [account activity api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/overview) which I can use to achieve this goal.

But, I do not understand how to implement Challenge-Response Checks, can you provide an example? how twitter checks this? it is through a post request to my site? to what specific URI they do this? I tried sending a pipedream url as webhook (to see what kind of request they were doing, but absolutely no request was shown)

Answer (score 1):

The account activity endpoint is part of Twitter's Premium product - so you may need to pay  to use it.  They have [comprehensive documentation on the CRC](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/securing-webhooks) - that includes a sample Python implementation.

I think you will find it easier to use to use the [`GET direct_messages/events/list`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/list-events) API call.

That will list all of the messages in your inbox for the last 30 days.